# how to update a variable field in a document using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using

```
db.hs.update( 
     {username: "hraj3116", "event_movie.name": "h"},
     {$set:{"event_movie.$.theatre":"vikas mall"}
     })
```

this to update in mongodb and this is working fine. How Can I use this using mongoose. I want "event_movie" as variable.

I am using

```
var  s = {'event_movie.name' : 'h'};
var event = {"event_movie.$.theatre" : "theatre"}; 
//event["event_movie.$.theatre"] = "theatre";
UserEventsDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
{ "username": username , s },
{ "$set": event },
{ "upsert": true, "new": true},
function(err, model){
    if (err){
        res.send(500, err);
    }else{
          res.send('done');
    }
});
```

Comment: I see that you have not accepted any of the answers to your questions. Though it is not an obligation, it helps the community and other users, in general if you accept answers that solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, in the query that we use to update via the shell or using mongoose API. In your case, you need to slightly modify your `query` parameter:

```
var query = {};
query["username"] = username;
query["event_movie.name"] = "h";
```

to produce the correct representation, which is:

```
{"username":username,"event_movie.name":"h"}
```

and then use it as:

```
var event = {};
event["event_movie.$.theatre"] = "theatre";
//event["someOtherField"] = "someOtherValue"; --> update some other field.

UserEventsDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
query,
{ "$set": event },
{ "upsert": true, "new": true},
function(err, model){
    if (err){
        res.send(500, err);
    }else{
          res.send('done');
    }
});
```

The way you currently build the query, it ends up being constructed as:

```
{"username":username,{"event_movie.name":"h"}}
```

which is wrong.

Comment: Can you please tell me for multiple update - means if event is an array of updates

Comment: @HimanshuRaj - Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/298489) the answer if it resolves your issue. Have edited my answer to add multiple fields for update, in the events object.

Comment: I was not knowing how to accept or about this accept concept

Comment: @HimanshuRaj - never mind. It is not intuitive to new members. Thanks for accepting.